# After installing Ubuntu 23.04 on HP laptop I do not have printer listed in settings. No gui for printer

Tags: printing, hp, canon

There are no printer settings in settings menu. Cups is installed. Gutenprint is installed. But no gui for printer settings.

HP 15-bs013ds  1.6Ghz Intel N3170 1 tb HD 4GB Ram Bios Version F.22

Install on desktop with same usb .iso has the printer settings installed.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried going to `http://localhost:631` in a web browser?

Comment: Hi Ray,  Thank you for the suggestion.  I can print from localhost:631.  The reason for the question was that my menu in settings did not have the gui for printers in it.  For some reason I enable the backports for 23.04 and now my menu is back.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the question was that my menu in settings did not have the gui for printers in it.  For some reason I enable the backports for 23.04 and now my menu is back.